# Golang XML Unmarshal value overwriting issue

Tags: xml, go

```
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="0547569653" status="Success">
    <Product xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd"
             xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
        <Identifiers>
            <MarketplaceASIN>
                <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
                <ASIN>0547569653</ASIN>
            </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
        <CompetitivePricing>
            <CompetitivePrices>
                <CompetitivePrice belongsToRequester="false" condition="Used" subcondition="Good">
                    <CompetitivePriceId>2</CompetitivePriceId>
                    <Price>
                        <LandedPrice>
                            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                            <Amount>9.95</Amount>
                        </LandedPrice>
                        <ListingPrice>
                            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                            <Amount>9.95</Amount>
                        </ListingPrice>
                        <Shipping>
                            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                            <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                        </Shipping>
                    </Price>
                </CompetitivePrice>
            </CompetitivePrices>
            <NumberOfOfferListings>
                <OfferListingCount condition="Any">113</OfferListingCount>
                <OfferListingCount condition="Used">72</OfferListingCount>
                <OfferListingCount condition="New">41</OfferListingCount>
            </NumberOfOfferListings>
        </CompetitivePricing>
        <SalesRankings>
            <SalesRank>
                <ProductCategoryId>book_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
                <Rank>48661</Rank>
            </SalesRank>
            <SalesRank>
                <ProductCategoryId>4209</ProductCategoryId>
                <Rank>31</Rank>
            </SalesRank>
            <SalesRank>
                <ProductCategoryId>6511974011</ProductCategoryId>
                <Rank>65</Rank>
            </SalesRank>
            <SalesRank>
                <ProductCategoryId>16587</ProductCategoryId>
                <Rank>93</Rank>
            </SalesRank>
        </SalesRankings>
    </Product>
</GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
```

I am trying to retrieve the "Rank" field only when the ProductCategoryId is equal to "book_display_on_website", however, in my current attempt it appears to set it Rank to the last SalesRank Entry (93) (it should be (48661)).  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Is this even possible using this Unmarshal method?  or is something like go-pkg-xmlx or gokogiri required? (I am coming from php and usually use simple_xml_parser on php for this type of stuff.)

```
type Data struct {
XMLName xml.Name `xml:"GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse"`
Item   []Item  `xml:"GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult"`
}

type Item struct {
Pcat string `xml:"Product>SalesRankings>SalesRank>ProductCategoryId"`
ASIN string `xml:"ASIN,attr"`
Rank string `xml:"Product>SalesRankings>SalesRank>Rank"`
}


    result, err := api.GetCompetitivePricingForASIN(asins)

    if (err != nil) {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    data := &Data{}

    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(result), data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(data.Item); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", data.Item[i])
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[`xml.Unmarshal()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) returns an `error` which you don't store and don't examine:

```
xml.Unmarshal([]byte(result), data)
if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

So the `err` you test in the next line is **not** the result of the `xml.Unmarshal()` but the same value returned previously by `api.GetCompetitivePricingForASIN(asins)`.

If you modify it to properly store the result of `Unmarshal()`:

```
err = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(result), data)
```

You will get the following error (wrapped):

```
expected element type <GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse> but have
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
```

Your model doesn't properly describe the XML input. Try the following structure to model the XML (the part you want to take out):

```
type Data struct {
    ASIN       string      `xml:"ASIN,attr"`
    SalesRanks []SalesRank `xml:"Product>SalesRankings>SalesRank"`
}

type SalesRank struct {
    Pcat string `xml:"ProductCategoryId"`
    Rank string `xml:"Rank"`
}
```

Using this model, you can print the results like this:

```
for _, item := range data.SalesRanks {
    fmt.Printf("Cat: %s; Rank: %s\n", item.Pcat, item.Rank)
}
```

Output:

```
Cat: book_display_on_website; Rank: 48661
Cat: 4209; Rank: 31
Cat: 6511974011; Rank: 65
Cat: 16587; Rank: 93
```

Try the complete program on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/K7cu0d_NEL).

Here is even a more simple and more informative printing:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", data)
```

Output (wrapped):

```
&{ASIN:0547569653 SalesRanks:[{Pcat:book_display_on_website Rank:48661}
  {Pcat:4209 Rank:31} {Pcat:6511974011 Rank:65} {Pcat:16587 Rank:93}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  your example works perfectly.  Gosh I am still confused however, because I only supplied an excert of the xml.  The xml I am trying to parse essentially has a multiples of my above example, back to back in a parent container.  So I will need to create a third struct and parent loop to handle that? correct?  I am a little confused trying to figure out the proper syntax for this.

Comment: to rephrase the above question, how would it work with multiple results in the xml?  example xml: https://play.golang.org/p/h8mvC4jYgp

Comment: @PaulR. The current `Data` type in my solution represents a `<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult >` tag. So if you have more of it, put a wrapper around it _both_ in the xml and in the Go code.

Comment: I feel really dumb because I cannot figure this out for the life of me :(

Comment: @PaulR. E.g. something like this: `type DataWrapper struct {Data []Data \`xml:"GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult"\`}` and in XML: `<root><GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult></GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult><GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult></GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult></root>`

Comment: opps, I spoke too soon.   I solved it using incorrect source xml..  (still working on the solution.)

Comment: nailed it. wow that took forever.  Can't wait till I am good at Golang!  Thanks again. Much appreciated.  (didn't use a wrapper)